# Crafter CMS 3.0 - deleted status pages

Tags: crafter-cms

After start Crafter CMS Authoring mode successfully, I create a new site as instructed at [Crafter CMS Your First Website](http://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/getting-started/your-first-website.html), but the results are not the same as the description of the tutorial, all pages have status "Deleted". See the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3sTE.png).

Please let me know what's wrong and how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to attach the tomcat logs and read through it to see what caused this. Also, you should attach the version and build numbers, it's under "Help > About"

Comment: Studio Version Number: 3.0.0-61d368
Build Number: 61d36822385fba145dc63a29cdb3cee5c201b05c

Build Date/Time: 08-01-2017 07:00:48 +0700

Comment: And tomcat logs: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_HtcCJTDTQQMF9ZdUg3cVNqams/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I also try to install on CentOS 7, everything works fine.

Comment: I couldn't find `catalina.out`, it should be under `logs/tomcat/catalina.out`. One thing to try real quick is to stop the system, delete the data folder, start again and see if you're still having the issue. If so, write down your steps that causes this and review clean logs.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know what the issue is here because there is no log file (link does not work) but I do notice on the image a couple of things:

1. Everything is showing a deleted status, typically if the item is NOT in the repository it does not show at all.  The deleted status typically shows up on historical dashboards.
2. Everything is lower cased/filename rather than internal name from the file

Hieu:
Anything you can tell us like:

- OS version
- Java version
- Steps you took / how to reproduce
- Other servers running for anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct answer to this is that there is an error in the Windows binary. I tried installing on 3 different Windows machines and had the same issue as the original poster. Plus the OP stated that the Linux distribution worked for them. I hope the Crafter people will look at this and make the correction.

Comment: Windows support is finally available in 3.0.1: http://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/release-notes/index.html [MS Windows Support
Updated Crafter CMS bundles to support MS Windows (7, 10, 2012 R2, 2016)
Updated Gradle to support build/deploy and run on Windows]

Comment: Thanks - I downloaded the 3.0.1 version and successfully installed and used it on Windows 10.